# Functional programming alternatives to while/break in Lisp

Tags: emacs, functional-programming, lisp, elisp

There is a list of strings. The idea is write a function that iterate on the list of the strings, and if a match is found return the string name, else `nil`. This can be written in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) language as

```cpp
string match-string(tmp)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); ++i)
    {
       if (tmp == stringList.at(i))
           return tmp;
    }
    return string(); // null string
}
```

But [in this post](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_break_loop.html) it is mentioned that generally loops are not used in Lisp and [there must be a functional way](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2007-10/msg00730.html). What could be the functional way to do this?

Comment: The link http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_break_loop.html does not say  that loops are not used in lisp, in fact it indicates "This page shows you how to exit a loop in emacs lisp." - which I believe is exactly the question you are asking? I suggest you go back to lisp fundamentals and examine exactly how the various flow control structures work. And perhaps list your lisp attempt rather than C++ pseudo code.

Comment: @robnick The first few lines in the link says "In many languages, there's “break” or “exit” keywords that you can use to exit a loop. In functional programing, usually you don't use loop/iteration, but sometimes a loop is just what you need."

Comment: Post your LISP code - not C++ pseudo code. LISP 100% supports loops and you can 100% exit "early" from them.

Comment: That's why Common Lisp has `return-from` and `return` and `prog` and `go`. But that link you gave shows using `catch/throw` in Elisp. What's wrong with that? (answer: nothing). :) ... Google found me this: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.co.il/2008/01/emergency-elisp.html.

Comment: I also wouldn't give too much weight to this page's advice w.r.t Lisp, since his Lisp code is very un-idiomatic.

Answer (score 5):

Loops are absolutely used in Lisp. Loops are more attractive in Lisps such as Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp that do not guarantee tail-call elimination.

If you insist on writing functionally, you can do that. It might look like this:

```
(defun find-string (string list)
  (if (null list)
      nil
    (if (equal string (car list))
        (car list)
      (find-string string (cdr list)))))
```

However in Emacs Lisp this code won't benefit from tail-call elimination, and may run slowly or blow the stack. It's probably better just to use a loop:

```
(defun find-string (string list)
  (loop for s in list
        when (equal s string) return s))
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct -- you can absolutely loop and return early in lisp. Loops are fine. Heck, Common Lisp's `loop` macro provides an entire language for the many different ways in which you might want to loop over things.

Recursion is the typical alternative, and it certainly is more common in functional programming; but whether it's a sensible replacement for a loop depends on the language implementation, and the code in question, because your stack space limits recursion depth.

For languages which internally optimise tail-recursive functions into loops, it doesn't matter which way you do it -- either way you end up with a loop.

If your language has no such optimisations (e.g. Emacs Lisp) or your function is not tail-recursive, and you do not have suitable known constraints on the data, then you'd want to write it as a loop in the first place.

A recursive version of your code is:

```el
(defun my-match-string (str list)
  (when list
    (if (string-equal str (car list))
        str
      (my-match-string str (cdr list)))))

(my-match-string "foo" '("x" "y" "foo" "z"))
```

Comment: Well gsg and I were writing answers at the same time and they turned out to be extremely similar, so I'd normally delete this; but as our commentaries are slightly different, it seems worthwhile leaving it here.